# Elasticsearch - Return documents only if all given terms are present

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a field called `message`. This field would contain a sentence.
Also, I have an array of terms. This Array would contain multiple words.
Something like,

```
"query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "message": [
                          "domain",
                          "rejected"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

Suppose, I want to return only those documents where `domain` and `rejected`, both must be present irrespective of their order in the sentence. What should the query be like?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage the [`intervals` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html) to achieve what you need, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "intervals": {
      "message": {
        "match": {
          "query": "domain rejected",
          "max_gaps": -1,
          "ordered": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this query says is basically this:

> within the `message` field, find the terms `domain` and `rejected` in no particular order and no particular proximity